# Logic of shell pattern matching

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards

What is the logical difference between

1. `ll -d !(.*@(ry|rc))`
2. `ll -d !(.*{ry,rc})`

?

Using them in my home dir, the second matches `.bash_history` and `.xinputrc` , while the first does not.

Note:

```
$ shopt extglob
extglob         on
```

Comment: Which shell is this?

Comment: @muru - This is bash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ll -d -- !(.*{ry,rc})
```

combines globbing and brace expansion. It is first expanded to:

```
ll -d -- !(.*ry) !(.*rc)
```

And the globs expanded individually. And the first one matches `.inputrc` (in `bash -O extglob` but not in `ksh` where that syntax comes from nor `zsh` in `ksh` emulation as those are hidden files and dot files are not explicitly requested).

You can verify that in a directory where those globs don't match any file (in which case the globs are left untouched, another `bash` misfeature which you can work around with `shopt -s failglob`) for instance in a directory where you don't have read permission:

```
$ chmod a-r .
$ bash -O extglob -c 'echo ll -d -- !(.*{ry,rc})'
ll -d -- !(.*ry) !(.*rc)
```

While in

```
ll -d -- !(.*@(ry|rc))
```

That's one glob.

Here, you can also do:

```
ll -d -- !(.*r[cy])
```

Or:

```
ll -d -- !(.*rc|.*ry)
```

Note that `bash` also includes `.` and `..` in that expansion. If you wanted to exclude them (as I'm sure you would) but still include hidden files, you'd need:

```
shopt -s dotglob
ll -d -- !([.]*@(rc|ry))
```

Or you could exclude them explicitely:

```
ll -d -- !(.*@(rc|ry)|.|..)
```

In `zsh -o extendedglob`, I'd do:

```
ll -d -- ^.*(rc|ry)(D)
```

(where `(D)` activates `dotglob`  for that glob only).

Comment: This answer points exactly to my question, and adds significant extra value.